# How to cut after a position to a specific character in unix

Tags: shell, unix, aix

I have a file name as dat_cpoybook_tab1_tab2_tabnm.txt. I want to cut from tab1. i.e my output will be:

tab1_tab2_tabnm

Please note that each time I need to cut it after two '_' to before '.txt'

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -Po '([^_]+_){2}[^_]+(?=\.txt)'

kent$  echo "a_bx_c_d_e_f_g.txt"|grep -Po '([^_]+_){2}[^_]+(?=\.txt)' 
e_f_g

kent$  echo "dat_cpoybook_tab1_tab2_tabnm.txt"|grep -Po '([^_]+_){2}[^_]+(?=\.txt)'
tab1_tab2_tabnm
```

#### awk:

```
awk -F'_|[.]txt' -v OFS="_" '$0=$(NF-3) OFS $(NF-2) OFS $(NF-1)'

kent$   echo "a_bx_c_d_e_f_g.txt"|awk -F'_|[.]txt' -v OFS="_" '$0=$(NF-3) OFS $(NF-2) OFS $(NF-1)'                                                                          
e_f_g
```

Comment: grep: Not a recognized flag: P
grep: Not a recognized flag: o

Comment: @user3726320 see another way in answer

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "dat_cpoybook_tab1_tab2_tabnm.txt"|awk -F'.' '{print $1}'|awk -F'_' '{ARR[1]=$0;} 
END {
v1=match(ARR[1],"_");
s1=substr(ARR[1],v1+1);
v2=match(s1,"_"); 
print substr(s1,v2+1);       
}'
```